# Would I install android studio with 2 GB RAM

Tags: windows, android-sdk

> Would I install Android Studio on my PC that have Window 7 and 2 GB RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 8 GB RAM recommended

2 GB of RAM isn't enough for any of the platforms. 3 GB RAM is the minimum plus 1 GB for Emulator = 4 GB minimum. However 8 GB RAM is recommended.

From [Android Studio Requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/#Requirements):

### Windows

- Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
- **3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended**; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
- 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

### Mac

- Mac® OS X® 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to 10.13 (macOS High Sierra)
- **3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended**; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
- 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

### Linux

- GNOME or KDE desktop
- Tested on Ubuntu® 14.04 LTS, Trusty Tahr (64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications)
- 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications
- GNU C Library (glibc) 2.19 or later
- **3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended**; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
- 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

**Note:** Probably works with Ubuntu's default Unity desktop which is based on Gnome but Google only says "Gnome" or "KDE" so this needs to be tested.

Answer (score 3):

No. You need at least 3 GB RAM. [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/#Requirements).

Comment: Your answer is very short, to the point, and gives a solid reference. Nicely done.. Although it might be noted: "Plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator"... and why would you have Android Studio if not using the emulator? So in reality, 4GB is the minimum RAM required for a usable installation.

Comment: @acejavelin No, you are not forced or obligated to use AVD. You don't have to. So it's 3 GB.